# Wxwidgets button resize

Tags: c++, button, resize, wxwidgets

How to resize the button?
The window was successful but the button was not.
Thanks for the help.

```
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
MyFrame::MyFrame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Hello World", wxDefaultPosition, { 500, 200 })
{
    wxButton *button = new wxButton(this, ID_Hello, "Hello", { 100, 50 }, { 50,50 });
}
```

Comment: Use a [wxSizer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_sizer.html). It will resize your button and also deal with other matters.

Comment: @Ripi2 Can you give an example?

Comment: See the "layout" sample provided with your distribution. Also, the [wiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxSizer) helps. Last, Google provides lots of results for "wxSizer tutorial"

Comment: Aside from using a sizer, you should probably *not* give it an explicit size, in which case it will have the best size for the given text.

Comment: @Max, on top of using sizers and not using explicit sizes in the control creation, keep in mind that creating one control will have the whole client area of the window fill with this control.

Comment: @Igor True, but only for wxFrame and if the control is the only child of that frame.

Comment: @Ripi2, true, but this is exactly the case the OP has.